# rspec - why does be_valid not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to do this:

```
  describe "should fail on create if the name is shorter than 5 characters" do
    group = Factory.build(:group, :name => "a")
    group.should be_invalid
    group.should have(1).error_on(:name)
  end
```

But I get the following error:

```
/spec/models/group_model_spec.rb:22: undefined local variable or method `be_valid' for #<Class:0x105d13ed0> (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:132:in `module_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:132:in `subclass'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:119:in `describe'
    from /xxxx/spec/models/group_model_spec.rb:15
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:132:in `module_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:132:in `subclass'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:119:in `describe'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/object.rb:6:in `describe'
    from /Users/bhellman/Sites/companyline/spec/models/group_model_spec.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:19
```

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you including rspec in your spec_helper file?

Comment: This happens to me when I forget to open the block: it "should blah" (without do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct syntax :

```
group.should_not be_valid
```

Comment: be_invalid should be available though

Comment: Same issue "undefined local variable or method `be_valid' for #<Class:0x105d13db8> (NameError)"

Comment: do you have a "require 'spec_helper'" in your spec ?

Comment: Beerlington, i may be wrong, by i don't think be_invalid exists in rspec.

Comment: @Spyros I do "require 'spec_helper". The factories are working just fine. Is group reserved perhaps?

Comment: Here is the full error trace. I think it might be reserved but I tried group2 and that didn't work ??

Comment: Ah crap, I had "describe "should " and not IT