# "undefined method `valid?'" in chapter 10 of Michael Hartl's tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm getting the following 3 errors for my code in the `micropost_spec`.rb file. How would I fix them? I think I'm following the tutorial exactly but it may be a problem with differing versions of Rails.

Ruby version: 1.9.2p320

Rails version: 3.2.13

Rspec: 2.11.1

Computer: Macbook pro OS X Mountain Lion

#### Errors

```
1) Micropost when user_id is not present 
   Failure/Error: it { User.should_not be_valid }
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `valid?' for #
   # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in '

2) Micropost with blank content 
   Failure/Error: it { User.should_not be_valid}
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `valid?' for #
   # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in '

3) Micropost when content is too long 
   Failure/Error: it { User.should_not be_valid }
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `valid?' for #
   # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in '
```

#### micropost_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Micropost do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(content: "Lorem ipsum") }

  subject { @micropost }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }
  its(:user) { should eq user }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @micropost.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with blank content" do
    before { @micropost = " "}
    it { should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when content is too long" do
    before { @micropost = "a" * 141 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, `@micropost = "a" * 141` etc are not correct; you should be modifying a *property* of the `Micropost`, not setting *the* value of `@micropost`. But your test subject is wrong, for some reason.

Comment: Maybe you ment `user` instead of `User` ?

Comment: @DaveNewton okay is there any other files I can post in order to solve the problem? Thanks for the response

Comment: @user2469211 Fix the `@micropost = ...` issue, edit your question to reflect the current content. Post the version of Ruby, Rails, RSpec at least.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added some of the info in the question. This is the current content though, I checked again. And I don't know what to change micropost to. It clearly says in the tutorial for it to be "micropost = "a" * 141" and this wasn't a problem before.

Comment: @user2469211 That makes zero sense; `@micropost` should be a `Micropost`, not a string. A string won't have a `valid?` method, whereas an `ActiveRecord` model will.

Comment: Actually, the tutorial says `@micropost.content = "a" * 141`. If you search for the text you have, it does not appear.

Comment: Here, the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384716/rspec-why-does-be-valid-not-work

Answer (score 0):

The error messages you are getting do not match the spec file you shared. The error messages show `User.should ....`, whereas your spec has an implicit subject.  The error reflects that you're indirectly calling `valid?` on the class `User` rather than the intended `@micropost`.

Comment: ok, is there any other files i can post to help solve the problem?

Comment: You've posted the relevant file (i.e. micropost_spec.rb). What I'm saying is that the result you're getting reflects executing some *other* version of the file. Compare the line numbers shown in the error messages with the line numbers of the file.